# TypeError: melt() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rapids

I am trying to use `melt()` function but it is showing me an error for passing 2 argument, which really weird because i am passing `id` as an argument and in my DataFrame i have only one `id` column, Although this error only comes when i use data which split from dataset by `train_test_split` function otherwise it is working fine.

**error message:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-676-bfd6b4109c81> in <module>
      1 # melt into long form
----> 2 X_train = X_train.melt('id')
      3 
      4 # group on melted id for idxmax/mean per "row"
      5 g = X_train.groupby('id').value

TypeError: melt() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

here **X_train** is a `cudf DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positional parameter is `self`, which is `X_train`.  `melt` expects its parameters to be specified by keyword.  Try `X_train.melt(id_vars=['id'])`.

Comment: this giving me error message `KeyError: "The following 'id_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: ['id']"`

Comment: `X_train = X_train.melt('id')`  is working when i use simple data(without split by `train_test_split` fubction.)

Comment: You'll have to look at the documentation to see which parameter you need.  Maybe `var_name='id'`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the signature of the melt function but it's possible that "melt" is a static function and you are calling it through an instance. In that case an extra "self" argument is passed to the function.